# Why im getting function redeclared fatal error when i have declared it only once?

Tags: php

```
function createStudentMarks($key)
{    echo "key".$key;exit;    }
```

This is my function.

```
$StudentMarks=createStudentMarks($key);
```

And i have called function in same file like this n im getting fatal error. Y is it so can anyone please help me

> Cannot redeclare createStudentMarks() (previously declared in /var/www/html/2016/S/Mcd_BuildStudentsMarks.php:85) in /var/www/html/2016/S/Mcd_BuildStudentsMarks.php on line 85 This is the error wat im getting exactly

Comment: Well the full error message should give you a few more clues, such as where it is being declared/redeclared

Comment: The parameter you're passing when you call the function, Is it defined ? Just define it and assign some value.    eg:  `$key = 100`  above your function call

Comment: parameter is coming from foreach loop no need of declaration

Comment: Function is declared in top n im using it in some foreach loop in further code

Comment: Cannot redeclare createStudentMarks() (previously declared in /var/www/html/2016/S/Mcd_BuildStudentsMarks.php:85) in /var/www/html/2016/S/Mcd_BuildStudentsMarks.php on line 85                                                   This is the error wat im getting exactly

Comment: Well,The question wasn't sufficient , There are already posts on this , Please refer,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953857/getting-a-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function-error

Comment: Thank you but i already had referred that it is different from wat i want

Comment: If the link above does not help you, then how can we. Remember we cannot see what you dont show us and we are not **clairvoyant**. _You must be declaring the function twice (PHP Does not make this stuff up) so now you just have to look for where that might be_

Comment: ok thank you so much for yo time n patience

Comment: Are you including this file twice? Or are you doing something crazy like defining the function inside another function?

Comment: Thank you Mark Baker. Im not including my file twice n there is no other function in whole file other than this

Comment: If you are using `include` or `require` replace it with `include_once` or `require_once`

Comment: Write `<?php exit;` at the beginning of the file with your function and look if you still get the errror.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, this is caused by accidentally `require`ing or `include`ing a file more than once.

This generally shows bad coding behavior, so first try to find if this is the case or not. Try to eliminate the second and so on `require`s or `include`s.

In any case, you can work around it but using `include_once` or `require_once`, which will not include the file on second or next calls.

Comment: Thank you all...my prob is solved...as i have told previously since it was inside foreach loop i was getting that error