# why i am getting Cannot redeclare httpGet() error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, gssapi

Below is the code in which I am getting error:

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($arr1); $i < $count; $i++) 
{
   print $arr1[$i]."\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r<br/><br/><br/>";
   $_SESSION['arrayvalue'] = "$arr1[$i]";
   $in = $arr1[$i];
   $in = str_replace(' ','+',$in); // space is a +
   //google site search start here
   function httpGet($url15)
   {
      $ch = curl_init();  
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url15);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
      //  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
      $output=curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $output;
   }

   $result15 = httpGet("https://www.google.com/cse?cx=003255331468891741234:xxxxxxxxx&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q='.$in.'&oq='.$in.'");
   echo $result15;
   //this is to get perticular tag/node value 
   $dom = new DomDocument;
   $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
   $dom->loadXML($result15);
   $N = $dom->getElementsByTagName('U');
   foreach ($N as $U) {
      echo $U->nodeValue, PHP_EOL."<br/>";
   }
}
```

This is the error which I am getting after showing one result:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare httpGet() (previously declared in 
/home/checkforplag/public_html/test/index.php:352) in
/home/checkforplag/public_html/test/index.php on line 352
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Fatal error: Cannot redeclare <function>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953857/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function)

Comment: You're declaring a function in a loop. It should be declared before `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening because you're trying to define the function `httpGet` multiple times (It's within the loop). Simply removing it to the outside, will define the function and allow it to be used later in the script. See also [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/1953870/4875631).

```
//google site search start here
function httpGet($url15)
{
   $ch = curl_init();  
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url15);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   //  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
   $output=curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $output;
}

for ($i = 0, $count = count($arr1); $i < $count; $i++) 
{
   print $arr1[$i]."\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r<br/><br/><br/>";
   $_SESSION['arrayvalue'] = "$arr1[$i]";
   $in = $arr1[$i];
   $in = str_replace(' ','+',$in); // space is a +

   $result15 = httpGet("https://www.google.com/cse?cx=003255331468891741234:xxxxxxxxx&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q='.$in.'&oq='.$in.'");
   echo $result15;
   //this is to get perticular tag/node value 
   $dom = new DomDocument;
   $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
   $dom->loadXML($result15);
   $N = $dom->getElementsByTagName('U');
   foreach ($N as $U) {
      echo $U->nodeValue, PHP_EOL."<br/>";
   }
}
```

Another alternative is to wrap your function in an if statement to see if the function already exists:

```
if ( !function_exists('httpGet') )
{
    function httpGet($url15)
    {
        //Function code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the function httpGet() out of the for loop.