# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare <method>

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ControllerSaleOrder::saveValue() in /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_admin_controller_sale_order.php on line 2617

Here's the code:

```
public function saveValue() {
  $json = array();
  if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $post = $this->request->post;
    $this->load->model('sale/order');
    $json['msg'] = $this->model_sale_order->saveNewValue($post);
  }
  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}

public function install() {
  if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $this->load->model('sale/order');
    $json['success'] = $this->model_sale_order->install();
  }
  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

Comment: Please share your complete code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Fatal error: Cannot redeclare <function>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953857/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function)

Answer (score 0):

in vq2-system_storage_modification_admin_controller_sale_order.‌​php there are two methods named saveValue(). Rename one