# laravel PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare for function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following function :

```
function get_user_browser() {
  $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $ub = 'unknown';
  if (preg_match('/Trident\/7.0; rv:11.0/', $u_agent)) {
    $ub = "ie ie-11";
  }
  elseif(preg_match('/MSIE/i', $u_agent)) {
    $ub = "ie";
  }
  elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i', $u_agent)) {
    $ub = "chrome";
  }
  elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i', $u_agent)) {
    $ub = "firefox";
  }
  elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i', $u_agent)) {
    $ub = "safari";
  }
  elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i', $u_agent)) {
    $ub = "opera";
  }
  return 'browser-'.$ub;
}
```

I have this function declare in two blades and I got this error :

> FPHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare get_user_browser() (previously declared in /home/storage/framework/views/0800146a0e35b205e9a66bb2f00ffb2f:7) in /home/storage/framework/views/0800146a0e35b205e9a66bb2f00ffb2f on line 7

How can I fix it?

Comment: are you loading those two blades at the same view??? or one in master blade and one in child blade????

Comment: apparently, you already have a declaration for this function in one of your views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Fatal error: Cannot redeclare <function>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953857/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function)

Comment: yes @webDev in the same view called layouts

Comment: have to add this    if(!function_exists('get_user_browser')) ??

Comment: You should create a helper file with functions like this. The view isn't a good place to define functions.

Answer (score 7):

Here a smart simple trick

add a file called helpers.php into your app folder

copy the function you wrote inside that file

add to composer.json under "autoload" the block:

```
 "files": [
  "app/helpers.php"
]
```

then run a composer update and you'll get the function available on all of your codebase

In this file you can add any helper functions you like, and as has already been told you should always avoid to write php code inside views

Comment: absolutely yes you can use it in every script of your project, for example in veiw by doing {{ get_user_browser() }}

Comment: And then you'll get  a bunch of log errors like "ERROR: Cannot redeclare get_user_browser() (previously declared... ". See https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/709

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that you're trying to declare the get_user_browser() function more than once

- Check if the function exists before declaring

  ```
  namespace App\Helpers;

   if (!function_exists('get_user_browser')) {
   function get_user_browser() {
       $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
       $ub = 'unknown';
       if (preg_match('/Trident\/7.0; rv:11.0/', $u_agent)) {
          $ub = "ie ie-11";
         }
       elseif(preg_match('/MSIE/i', $u_agent)) {
          $ub = "ie";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i', $u_agent)) {
          $ub = "chrome";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i', $u_agent)) {
          $ub = "firefox";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i', $u_agent)) {
          $ub = "safari";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i', $u_agent)) {
          $ub = "opera";
       }
       return 'browser-'.$ub;
       }
    }
  ```

Then, when you call the function, you need to include the namespace

```
 $browser = \App\Helpers\get_user_browser();
```

This worked out well to me.