# generate 14 digit random number in php

Tags: php, random

heres my code

```
while($x <= $num) {
$code = rand(1,666666).rand(2,88888888);

$INC = qry_run("Insert into ms_code2 (code) Values(".$code.")");

$x++;
}
```

the main problem is when this loop work sometimes it generate 14 number sometimes 10 and sometimes 12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't get into a discussion about how "random" we can ever really get, I am pretty sure this will generate a number random enough! :)

```
function randomNumber($length) {
    $result = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

..and of course then it's just `echo randomNumber(14);`

Comment: i want 14 digit number ex: 11222233334444

Comment: @malikali And that's exactly what this answer does.

Comment: and i want to save in sql table like if user type i want o generate 20 numbers set

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare generateCode() (previously declared in D:\xampp\htdocs\working\ihsan-sports\ms-panel\add-process\code-process.php:29) in D:\xampp\htdocs\working\ihsan-sports\ms-panel\add-process\code-process.php on line 29

facing this error

Comment: Hi Malik, I don't think that's related to the code I posted. It sounds like you pasted the function twice. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953857/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function

Comment: you redeclearing same named function. Need to turn off previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple trick to generate (n) number of random numbers

```
function generateCode($limit){
    $code = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) { $code .= mt_rand(0, 9); }
    return $code;
}
echo generateCode(14);
```

This above function returns **14** random digits.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest one could be this also, Here we are using `array_map` and `range` to iterate over callback function and maintain a string.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/793529)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string="";
array_map(function($value) use(&$string){
    $string.=mt_rand(0, 9);
}, range(0,13));
echo $string;
```