# when i display my wordpress website post on other php script which resides in the same directory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

It is not Displaying it and when enable ERROR REPORTING to Check Issue it Show me Fatal error: Cannot redeclare clean_url() (previously declared in /home/a107853262/public_html/TECHNICALLY-SPEAKING.ORG/small-seo-tools/core/functions.php:237) in /home/a107853262/public_html/TECHNICALLY-SPEAKING.ORG/wp-includes/deprecated.php on line 2039.  Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to re-declare the function clean_url().

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953857/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function#1953870)

Also clean_url() is deprecated and should be replaced by esc_url(). [WordPress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/clean_url/)